# ASP/PHP & Access mdb file / image file path

Tags: php, ms-access, asp-classic

--- Revised with detail because of helpful pertaining comments ---

Essential I just want to upload one or multiple image files into a folder while saving its file path information onto a MDB file, so in that way I can open the image onto the webpage through the saved file path.

From what I understand from my own research and from comments from others on this thread is that there is several ways to do this.

1 - I could just solely use ASP to upload the image file into a folder and save its file path into a record within a recordset in a MDB file.

This option would be great but also more time consuming cause I would need to figure out what code to use to send the image file to a specific folder, to take the file path information and write it to a MDB recordset record, and to provide similar security in how I currently have the PHP code setup in defining if its a actual image file or not.

2 - I could also use PHP to upload the image file into a folder (already have the code for) and also use PHP to write the file path to the MDB file. (don't have the code for)

This option would be best since I have the upload file to folder portion of it done. Yet I'm not sure how to send its file path information directly from PHP to the MDB file, plus the other concern would be on how to utilize the user session with it.

3 - Lastly, there might be a way to take the info from the PHP variable and send it to a ASP variable and then from there I can write the file path into the MDB file.

The last option which is the shortest route because I already have the PHP portion of upload file to folder done and I already know how to write to the MDB file using ASP. Problem is, how do I pass the variable information from the PHP portion to the ASP portion

Basically from the paragraph above, that'll require figuring out how to take the upload file path info from the $target_file :example - ../uploads/image.jpg

Then placing that info into one or a array ASP variable for one or several records in a recordset, since the current upload php code allows for one or more image uploads.

As is what I'm currently using is HTML and PHP to upload image files and I plan on using ASP with the page, however passing the PHP variable to the ASP variable is what I'm stuck on. I know its possible to pass info from one code to another like how you can use Ajax to pass info from JS to PHP, just not sure how to do that with PHP to ASP.

Below is the current code in the HTML file

```
<form action="php/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="filesToUpload" style="margin-top:10px">Select Images to Upload</label><br>
  <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" multiple="multiple" style="display:inline-block">
  <output id="filesInfo" style="display:inline-block"></output>
  <i class="fa fa-photo fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Upload Image(s)" style="margin-top:5px" name="submit"><br><br>
</form>
```

As for the PHP code, I would love to show all of it on here but its giving me issues to add it onto here, so I'll show the meat of it and leave out the security portion of it.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name']); $i++){
$target_dir = "../uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'][$i]);
$uploadOk = 1;

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded. ";
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filesToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["filesToUpload"]["name"][$i]). " has been uploaded. ";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. ";
    }
}
}
```

I also know that I could use a ASP variable that might be stated as:

```
Dim imagePath
imagePath =
```

But that's where I get stuck on how to apply the content from the PHP $target_file variable to the ASP imagePath variable.

Comment: We won't write the code for you. Show us what you've tried and what errors you encounter, then we'll take it from there. There are plenty of resources on the web to cover this.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe it's just me, but I don't understand what you are asking. What are you doing in ASP?

Comment: To Andre - Thank you for your comment and I agree with you. Though it was the context of how Paul said it and what he did.

Comment: To Bob - I'm using ASP to add info into a MDB file, the info being the file path of a image file. So lets say for example the Field Name 1 = image, the Data Type 1 = Text, with Field Name 2 = UserID, and Data Type 2 = AutoNumber and that's in the Design View. In the default view the rows would contain the info per user image. So in this case instead of storing the image directly in the MDB, just want to save its file path, to open the image on a webpage through its file path in a persons user session. Not sure how else to explain that.

Comment: @user3730410: to reply to specific users, please use the @ as I have done here, so they get a msg in their inbox. About the comment, yes, it could perhaps been written a bit nicer, but being nice to new users is not too high a priority at SO, unfortunately.

Comment: About the problem: at the core you need to pass a variable from PHP to ASP (can't help with that, sorry). Saving to Access mdb seems to be irrelevant to the problem, so you might revise your question, remove everything non-essential, and perhaps add the PHP tag.

Comment: If what you're asking is how do you write values to a JET (*.mdb) database in Classic asp then there are plenty of tutorials on the internet - including this one. http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_add.asp. If you're asking how to upload in Classic ASP then you need either a third party component or a class file.  If you're using php to upload then I'd suggest you use the same php script to write to the database, you can connect through ODBC if you're running php on Windows

Comment: @John - I already know how to write values to mdb, plus w3schools should update their info to include ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for iis7 and above. I don't wan't to upload the images to the mdb, just file path of the image into a record. I already have the file path in a PHP variable but was hoping to pass it from the PHP variable to a ASP variable and write the file path to the record on the MDB file that way. Though I like your PHP suggestion, but do you have links that'll show how or a link for the passing of info from the PHP to ASP variable(s).

Comment: The usual way to pass variables to an asp script is through the Request object - `Request.Form("imagepath")` for post data, `Request.Querystring("imagepath")` for get data or just `Request("imagepath")` if you don't need to distinguish.  Presumably there's a way to make an HTTP Request in PHP.  Re ACE, the JET OLEDB driver ships with IIS7, the ACE driver doesn't, so I suspect JET is still more popular, and it's the driver you would want to use if your database has an .mdb rather than an .accdb extension

Comment: @John: I see where you're going with this, because in the upload.php file I can use <!--#include file="Upload.asp"--> and in that file I would use the Request in the following way - Request.Form("filesToUpload[]") - since that would be the correct use for the post data. But that would only write the file name or file itself and not the folder path, which I would then have to add the folder path into the Upload.asp file as well. So question is, will it write the file name or the file itself when I do that. Because I don't want the image file itself in the MDB file.

Comment: You can't include an asp file in a php script, the php interpreter wouldn't be able to understand it.  What you need to do within upload php is assign values to the variables you want to send to the asp page and then request the asp page from within your upload.php.  I'm not an expert with php but cURL looks promising.  You would probably need to send the request to the full external url of your asp page.  This is why I suggest that you have a single script, in either asp or php, which handles both the upload and the database insert query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to those that tried to help but I was able to find the answer to my question, so I decided to share the solution.

I went with option one -

**1 - I could just solely use ASP to upload the image file into a folder and save its file path into a record within a recordset in a MDB file.**

**This option would be great but also more time consuming cause I would need to figure out what code to use to send the image file to a specific folder, to take the file path information and write it to a MDB recordset record, and to provide similar security in how I currently have the PHP code setup in defining if its a actual image file or not.**

I went with that option because I found a simple, easy and cost effective solution in the following link:
http://planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8525&lngWId=4

The content in the above link provides what I was looking for and much more, plus its easy to integrate. It also has sample scripts to work with as well.